# what is the meaning of the words color in javascript

Tags: javascript, colors, visual-studio-2017

For example, if i put a function it will appear with the color blue, but i don`t know the meaning of the color orange yellow purple etc...
i have already tried to search for my answer in google but i have fond nothing

```js
function
```

```css
 css
```

```html
html
```

Comment: You'd have to look what color scheme you're using in visual studio. The colors aren't standardized for JavaScript.

Comment: Do you mean the syntax-highlighting in the Visual Studio editor?

Comment: [Syntax Highlighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_highlighting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the editor you are using for writing your code, they will show text in different colors and/or fonts based on the category of the terms (function, variable, etc.). To see exactly how your editor is doing this, try looking in its Settings.